# Array not getting correct output in php

Tags: php

Learning php these days. At first sorry if its a dumb query.

```
<?php

$cfg['x']['y']['z'] = "TRUE"; 
$cfg['x']['y'] = "FALSE";

print_r($cfg['x']['y']['z']); //what to change here to get required output

?>
```

**Output:** F

But my expected output is TRUE

What should I change?

Comment: `$cfg['x']['y']['z']` is basically `($cfg['x']['y'])['z']` - and after the second assignment, `$cfg['x']['y']` is a _string_ ("FALSE"), not an array. Any attempt to access it as an array is incorrect by definition; it's _helpfulness_ of PHP that allow you to do it, but `'z'` is treated as a zero index at a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here `$cfg['x']['y']['z']` no longer exists because you overwrote `$cfg['x']['y']` which contained `$cfg['x']['y']['z']`.

```
 $cfg['x']['y'] = "FALSE";
```

Here you try to get the `'z'` element of the `$cfg['x']['y']` variable. It's a string since you put `FALSE` in quotes. `'z`' is converted to zero by PHP's type juggling. So the `0` element of the string `'false` is `F`

```
print_r($cfg['x']['y']['z']);
```

There's no real way to make this work the way you intend. You should be assigning `FALSE` to a new variable or turn `$cfg['x']['y']` into an array so it can hold multiple values:

```
$cfg['x']['y'] = array(
    'z' = "TRUE",
    'newKey' = ""
);
```

FYI, if you intend to use `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` as boolean values you should not wrap them in quotes or else they are strings. As a result both `"TRUE"` and `"FALSE"` evaluate to `true` also due to PHP's type juggling.

Comment: Thanks a lot John for your brief description